# Lie Subgroups of $SL(2,\mathbb{R})$

Tags: group-theory, lie-algebra

I'm wondering about the Lie subgroups of $SL(2,\mathbb{R})$. 
It's Lie algebra is the algebra of real traceless matrices and has basis elements $$L_0 = \left(
\begin{matrix} 
-1 & 0 \\
0 & 1 
\end{matrix} \right), L_+ = \left(
\begin{matrix} 
0 & 1 \\
0 & 0 
\end{matrix} \right), L_- = \left(
\begin{matrix} 
0 & 0 \\
1 & 0
\end{matrix} \right).$$

I think I can use the exponential map to find lie subgroups associated with each of these basis vectors. $G= Exp(tX)$, but I'm struggling to see how to do this.

Comment: Would [math.se] be a better home for this question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the standard expansion of exponential to write,
$$G = e^{tX} = \mathbb 1+tX+\frac12 t^2 X^2+\frac1{3!} t^3 X^3+\cdots$$
Note that $L_0^2=\mathbb1$, $L_+^2=0$ and $L_-^2=0$. Therefore,
$$\begin{split}e^{t L_0} &= Cosh[t] \ \mathbb1 + Sinh[t] L_0 = \begin{pmatrix}e^{-t}&0\\0&e^t\end{pmatrix}\\
e^{t L_+} &= \mathbb 1+ t L_+ = \begin{pmatrix}1&t\\0&1\end{pmatrix}\\
e^{t L_-} &= \mathbb 1+ t L_- = \begin{pmatrix}1&0\\t&1\end{pmatrix}\end{split}$$
In fact, using these three matrices you can generate any element of $\mathbb{SL}(2,\mathbb R)$ by multiplication.